# ArrayList with even or odd

Tags: java

I would like to checking if an element is even or odd. What is wrong with my code?

bad operand types for binary operator '%' first type: java.lang.String second type: int, line 16
incompatible types: java.util.ArrayDeque cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList, line 44

```
class ArrayExample{

public void printMethod(ArrayList<String> theList){
    String value = null;
    for (int n=0; n < theList.size(); n++){
        value = theList.get(n);
        //checking if an element is even or odd
        if (value.length % 2 == 0){
             System.out.println("even");
             System.out.println(value);
        } else {
             System.out.println("odd");
             System.out.println(value);

    }}}} 

class Calc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<String> storeQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt((40 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        String z = new String(new char[value]).replace("\0", "z");
        storeQueue.add(z);
        System.out.println(storeQueue);
    }

    ArrayExample samp = new ArrayExample();
    samp.printMethod(storeQueue);

}}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but the way you use `Random` will likely not yield random results (or very bad ones). Re-use a random instance instead of creating several instances in a loop (e.g. by storing it in a static field)

Comment: "What is wrong with my code?" => The error message clearly told you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply using ArrayList instead of ArrayDeque unless you want to perform FIFO operation. Also you might realised that your array is consisted of String, `mod` operation here should take input as integer. So you can use this random:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
```

Comment: you have two problem, the first one is your argument is a string instead of an integer. second you can't convert directly from a arraydeque to arraylist.

```
bad operand types for binary operator '%' first type: java.lang.String second type: int, line 16 incompatible types: java.util.ArrayDeque cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList, line 44
```

so basically you can convert arraydeque to arraylist by using Array.asList(storeQueue.toArray())

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 changes required to make the program work:

1. Change the operands of % operator to Integer (Use value.length in place of value)
2. Change the argument to printMethod from ArrayDeque type to 'ArrayList' type.

**Here is the working solution, with these 2 changes:**

```
// File name: Calc.java

import java.util.*;

class ArrayExample{

public void printMethod(ArrayList<String> theList) {
    String value = null;
    for (int n=0; n < theList.size(); n++){
        value = theList.get(n);
        //checking if an element is even or odd
        if ((value.length()) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("even - " + value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("odd - " + value);
        }
    }
  }
} 

public class Calc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<String> storeQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt((40 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        String z = new String(new char[value]).replace("\0", "z");
        storeQueue.add(z);
        System.out.println(storeQueue);
    }

    ArrayExample samp = new ArrayExample();
    samp.printMethod(new ArrayList<String>(storeQueue));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac Calc.java

> java Calc
[zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]
[zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, zzzzzz]
[zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, zzzzzz, zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]
[zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, zzzzzz, zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz]
...
...
...

even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzz
odd - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
odd - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
odd - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
odd - zzzzzzzzz
odd - zzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
odd - zzzzz
even - zzzz
even - zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class ArrayExample method printMethod expect ArrayList as parameter, but in main method you try to pass ArrayDeque which is not compatible with ArrayList.

To resolve this problem you should change parameter declaration in printMethod to ArrayDeque, but still there is a problem becouse ArrayDeque dont have .get method.

I propose to change body of method to foreach loop.

And another bug in this code is you try modulo on String but you need do it on its length. You cannot modulo on text, rather you should use it on text length.

```
class ArrayExample {
    public void printMethod(ArrayDeque<String> theList) {
        String value = null;
        for (String s : theList) {
            if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("even");
                System.out.println(value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("odd");
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you main class can stay the same as you write.

Answer (score 0):

It works - @Gopinath

```
   // File name: Calc.java

import java.util.*;

class ArrayExample{

public void printMethod(ArrayList<String> theList) {
    String value = null;
    for (int n=0; n < theList.size(); n++){
        value = theList.get(n);
        //checking if an element is even or odd
        if ((value.length()) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("even - " + value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("odd - " + value);
        }
    }
  }
} 

public class Calc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDeque<String> storeQueue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt((40 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        String z = new String(new char[value]).replace("\0", "z");
        storeQueue.add(z);
        System.out.println(storeQueue);
    }

    ArrayExample samp = new ArrayExample();
    samp.printMethod(new ArrayList<String>(storeQueue));
    }
}
```